# How to restart video on Exoplayer after ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using **Exoplayer** with a base of the **DemoPlayer**. 
I want to **restart/replay** the video from beginning on some user action **after** that **ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED** is dispatched.

I've tried to use `seekTo(0)` and `mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);` after but it didn't do anything, at all.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I've updated the library to ExoPlayer `r1.4.2` and it does the job...

```
    mPlayer.seekTo(0);
    mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true); // replay from start
```

// Pause video after restart

```
    mPlayer.seekTo(0);
    mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
```

Comment: This solution replays the video from start.

Comment: sending false works for me to make it to start point and pause the player.. mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);

Comment: Welcome dude.. Thank you.

Comment: but due to usage of this line mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);  @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        Log.d(VideoDetailActivity.class.getName(),"onPlayerStateChanged:"+playbackState);
        if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED) {  // this if condition if getting called twice.How to avoid ?

Answer (score 6):

A video can be seamlessly looped using a LoopingMediaSource. The following example loops a audio/video indefinitely. It’s also possible to specify a finite loop count when creating a LoopingMediaSource.

```
MediaSource source = new ExtractorMediaSource(audioUri, ...);
// Loops the audio indefinitely.
LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(source);
```

or add a **listener**

```
playerExo.addListener(new ExoPlayer.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

                switch(playbackState) {
                    case ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:
                        break;
                    case ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED:
                        playerExo.seekTo(0);
                        break;
                    case ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE:
                        break;
                    case ExoPlayer.STATE_PREPARING:
                        break;
                    case ExoPlayer.STATE_READY:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayWhenReadyCommitted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

            }
        });
        playerExo.seekTo(0);
        playerExo.setPlayWhenReady(true);//replay from start



/*  If you want to Pause audio/video and restart
 mPlayer.seekTo(0);
 mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);*/
```

You can check the Exoplayer latest release to be up to date:

[Exoplayer Releases](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/releases)

Comment: Question isn't asking about looping a video.

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me

```
 @OnClick(R.id.image_button_play)
public void play(){
    Log.d(TAG, "play: clicked");
    //If video has finished then set Exoplayer to 0
    if (simpleExoPlayer.getPlaybackState() == Player.STATE_ENDED){
        simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(0);
    }
    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Hello gouri panda, this solution plays an infinite loop, so you should change to false `setPlayWhenReady` and allows the user to click play again